# If it possible to get average response time to variable in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Obviously, I know that I have response time in .jtl file and in listener called Aggregate report, but I'm looking for way to get reponse time of request to variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request
2. Put the following code into PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put("responseTime", String.valueOf(prev.getTime()));
   ```

It will get elapsed time for the sampler (in milliseconds) and store it into `${responseTime}` variable. You can add sampler label as prefix or postfix to distinguish response times for different samplers.

`prev` is a shorthand for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) instance.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you , it's exatcly what I was looking for, but generally I've got question : Why did you use , String.valueOf before (prev.getTime), Does it necessary?

Comment: There are 2 methods: `vars.put(String, String)` - in that case cast to string is mandatory, and `vars.put(String, Object)` - cast is not necessary. See [JMeterVariables class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) - `vars` is a shorthand to its instance

Comment: Dmitri, tkank You for explanation, this solution is correct when I want to get response time of previous request,but now I wonder how to get response time for whole sample , in my case for Transaction controller, which consist of three requests?